# PDF Receipt not included with Membership Renewal email

Tags: civimember

A PDF version of the receipt is added to the email that goes out with new membership sign-ups, but is absent from the email that is sent for membership renewals.

Comment: How does the renewal happen? Through online form or automatically?

Comment: This is actioned by our treasurer when the payment is received in the bank account. So it is completed manually by clicking on "renew" in the membership record and following the process required, including sending a receipt.